# freemarker sort by date; need to change date format

Tags: freemarker

hope someone can help me... i'm using freemarker and need to do the following.

i got a list that i have to sort by a field called course_start_date. this is a date field of this form: dd MM yyyy (day month year). unfortunately sorting isn't correct as i need the date in this form yyyyMMdd to run it as supposed to use for sorting by date.

the big question: how can i change the date format? i tried this but i just got an error.
[#list?sort_by("veranstaltung.first_course_date".pattern('YYYYMMDD')") as veranstaltung]

hope someone can help me.

best regards,
daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?sort_by` won't do such thing, it's for fairly simple cases. Generally, the data should be already sorted when the template gets it (so one may argues that `?short_by` shouldn't exist at all). But at the very least, dates should be in the data model as dates (like `java.util.Date` or such), not as text, and then `?sort_by` would sort them correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hints. Unfortunately i don't have access to Java. What i described is the possibilities that customers have to create reports (with FTL), but that's all a part of an ERP-solution. I will have to contact them as it seems to generate the output i need.

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @ddekany's answer, in general and specially in your case it's advisable to sort the list before processing the template.

Apart from the problem of date formatting there are errors in

```
[#list?sort_by("veranstaltung.first_course_date".pattern('YYYYMMDD')") as veranstaltung]
```

The parameter of the `?sort_by` directive should be the field of the item in the loop. And the list object is missing.. Should be like:

```
<#list item_list?sort_by("first_course_date") as veranstaltung>
    ${veranstaltung.first_course_date}
</#list>
```